# Change data representation structure in QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have custom QSortFilterProxyModel class that i'm using with  QFileSystemModel and displaying it in QTreeView. I need to do the following: if there exists folder and file that has identical names (ignoring file extension) files from folder must be docked to this file. For example i have Creatures.txt file and Creatures folder that contains two txt files. I want hide it from final view and display as shown in second picture.

[image]

[image]

To my understanding QSortFilterProxyModel is used only for filtering and sorting, not for changing data structure. I also need to create/drag-and-drop files in viewport.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather tricky to do, because there is no flag to toggle the visibility of an item in the model.

Instead you could create your own proxy model that omits these items. (That means to reimplement rowCount(), data(), flags() etc. appropriately.)

But if it is Ok to change the visibility on the view side, as a workaround it might be easier for you to use QTreeView::setRowHidden() instead.

Edit: Perhaps overriding QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow() is even easier.

Comment: I already created my proxy model for filtering items. Problem is in changing structure of model.

Comment: @Kamanji You have to return QModelIndex with different parent, row and column. It would help a lot if you publish the proxy code.

Comment: @eyllanesc [Here](https://pastebin.com/V6pe4DB9) is my reimplementation of filterAcceptRow function. The only problem that i have now is to change item's parent. If i can do this using Proxy model and then be able to retrieve index from original model it's all i need. 
I also thought of building custom itemModel and then doing all restructuring in it

Comment: @Kamanji Since you want to change the parent, you could give me an example

Comment: @eyllanesc What kind of example ? I'm using proxy model on QFileSystemModel and working with files. I gave example in my question, if there anything unclear about it i can explain it

Comment: @Kamanji I understand that you want to hide the item if the file name is the same as a folder, but what I do not understand is that you say you want to change the structure, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @eyllanesc Im my example i have two object in treeView Creatures and Creatures.txt  (Folder and txt file) i want to display all files from folder as if they were under text file and hide folder. I do not want to affect file system in any way, only what will be displayed to end user